# Is a legend for graduated circlemarkers in r leaflet map possible?

Tags: r, leaflet

I am working with a graduated circle r leaflet map, with circlemarkers all of the same color, but with different sizes. I need a legend that reflects this. But in all the documnetation and examples I've read addLegend is based on color not on size. I don't have any experience with css, but if there's a className  based solution I'd be open to that as well.

```
  leaflet(data) %>% 
  addTiles('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')

  map%>% setView(lat = lat, lng = lng, zoom = 7)

  map %>% addCircleMarkers(~lng, ~lat, popup=~paste(data$radius), 
  weight = 1,radius = ~data$radius, color="#800080")
```

Comment: How does R utilize CSS?

Comment: It was a guess, but there was this argument for addLegend  in leaflet: **className: extra CSS classes to append to the control, space separated**

Comment: I edited the post to take the css tag out.